# How do I debug JavaScript written in Scratchpad that comes with Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want a stand-alone `editor` and `debugger`, basically an `IDE` for `JavaScript`. I am presently using a mix of just running stand-alone scripts on the command line and editing them in `Notepad++`, and sometimes the `Scratchpad` that comes in `Firefox Developer tools`.

But the `Debugger` in `Firefox Developer Tools` does not show me the sources from `ScratchPad`. How do I make it show them?

Besides, I am unable to set breakpoints in the `ScratchPad` editor.

Comment: This is not a tool recommendation question. It asks how to use a specific programming tool for a specific task.

Comment: This question does kind of have the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364124/how-to-watch-variables-in-the-firefox-scratchpad. Even if it is not good news.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate of the much broader question of "how can I debug my Javascript" and yes this kind of question does have an answer. I came here specifically because I wanted to find out if I could set break points in Scratchpad, and had the question more or less answered (only through the "debugger" keyword). So it was of use to me.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was fixed in Firefox 47 (see [bug 1252077](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1252077)), you can now use `debugger;` statements in your Scratchpad code or set breakpoints directly in the Debugger. The Scratchpad script's source should appear there after you have run the script at least once. Make sure you have Dev Tools open.

It's a bit awkward though since Scratchpad scripts don't update in the Debugger window after they were modified in the Scratchpad, you need to refresh the page you're on first or use `Execute` → `Reload and Run` in the Scratchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Scratchpad works great except I can't figure out how to access the breakpoint scope in it. Anyone have an idea how to do that? Was automatic in Firebug.